# How to fix this Caesar Cipher to include upper case letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a program that encrypts a file using caesar cipher, the only problem is that it does not include upper case letters, as they are not included in my list. Is it possible to include upper case letters in this somehow, or do i need to make all characters lowercase?

My current code:

```
encrypt = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 'ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789abcdef')
decrypt = str.maketrans('ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789abcdef', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')

filename = "abc_abd.txt"

with open(filename, "r") as readfile:
    with open(filename+'-encrypted.txt', 'w+') as writefile:
        for line in readfile:
            print(line.translate(encrypt), file=writefile)
```

I'd like for the program to include upper case letters in the shift, but they are not included.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import string
>>> charset = ''.join(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + ''.join([str(i) for i in range(0, 10)]))
>>> charset
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
>>> delta = 6
>>> encrypt = str.maketrans(charset, charset[delta:] + charset[:delta])
>>> decrypt = str.maketrans(charset[delta:] + charset[:delta], charset)

>>> with open(r'C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/abc_abd.txt') as f1:
...     for line in f1:
...             print(f'Original: {line}')
...             encrypted_line = line.translate(encrypt)
...             print(f'Encrypted: {encrypted_line}')
...             decrypted_line = encrypted_line.translate(decrypt)
...             print(f'Unencrypted: {decrypted_line}')
...
Original: this is a test
Encrypted: znoy oy g zkyz
Unencrypted: this is a test
Original: number 9 in here
Encrypted: tAshkx f ot nkxk
Unencrypted: number 9 in here
```

Note that I'm assuming you're starting from scratch here, to implement including upper case letters.  Also, I hope you're not storing anything important in this, it's not true encryption by any means.  I would not consider this safe for storing anything.